# Four letters - one sound!

Tags: phonics

Whilst teaching phonics today, we encountered the word 'through' and I was asked 'What is it called when four letters make one sound'?  It's a fair question and I haven't a clue!

None of the phonic support sites seem to have the answer either.

Obviously not a digraph or trigraph....... a 'quadgraph' perhaps?!

Help!

Comment: *Quadgraph* works: http://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_a_quadgraph

Comment: Since we're coining a term, let's keep the roots in the same etymological soil:  *tetragraph*.  (We could also play for the humor of the moment, roll our eyes to the ceiling, and say "You call it 'English'.")

Comment: This is more tongue-in-cheek than serious, but you could say that _through_ has a digraph (_ou_) adjacent to two silent letters (_gh_), while _cough_ has consecutive digraphs (_ou_ and _gh_). @Rob - for what it's worth, Wikipedia has an entry on [tetragraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetragraph).

Comment: @J.R.: In words like "cough," I think it's more regular to think of it as a monograph(?) *o* followed by a trigraph *-ugh* (representing /f/). All the word spelled with *gh* and pronounced with /f/ have a *u* before the *gh.*

Comment: @sumelic - I like it; that explains _laugh_ quite well.

Comment: Wikipedia also has a [list of Latin script tetragraphs in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin-script_tetragraphs#English).

Answer (score 7):

I realize that the principle behind "phonics" is that English spelling does represent something
about pronunciation; unfortunately, what it actually represents is Middle English pronunciation.
Thus, this isn't a situation where "four letters make one sound", because

- letters don't make sounds, at least not in Modern English.
  English spelling simply doesn't represent English speech;
- and even if letters did make sounds, the `GH` at the end wouldn't make any sound at all.
  The `GH` in *through* is **silent**. The single vowel /u/ in /θru/ is represented by the `OU`.

And there isn't a technical term for it, either, though you can make one up if you like.